# Percentage of area within a buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, land-use

I have a layer containing the land use of a specific area,and a buffer. I would like to calculate the percentage of each category contained in the buffer. For example in the picture i want to know the percentage of the gray parts and orange parts within the buffer. I have tried with intersect but it doesn't work
[image]

Comment: Why did it not work? Any errors?. As it would be the way to go.

Comment: When i do the intersect operations between the land use layer and the buffer, it creates a new layer that does not contain anything. It is like the intersection is empty

Comment: Are the layers in the same coordinate reference?

Comment: Ok now it seems wotking,one of the layer had a wrong coordinate reference,thank you